# InDesign – Subgrid within a larger page

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, grids

I'm working on a panel design for a museum in indesign. The design has a sections of text and images contained by a box. Right now I'm using a text box with inset spacing to see the inner margins of the section, like this:

[image]

However, this is not a great solution for me because I can't see the guides once I click off of the text box:

[image]

Is there a way to set indesign so that I can see the inset spacing margins  all of the time without having to click on the object?

EDIT:

I do have a grid set up:

[image]

However the grid doesn't allow me to create consistent "padding" around subsections of the page, like this.
[image]

Comment: Ideally you would configure guides on master pages rather than using a page-covering text box.

Comment: Hard to see what's going on, when we can't see the whole page. Why can't you just use ordinary page margins? Is it because you have several similar panels on one big page? The you could create the panels in one document with the page size set to the size of the panels and then place the pages of that document in a larger one.

Comment: Your layout *is* quite complex. I can understand why you want to use the inset spacing of the text frames for padding. I don't think there is a way to force the inset to be visible all the time. You can still snap to it though.

Comment: how do you snap to the inset?

Comment: Like all other snapping. Drag an object near the inset and it will snap to it (if you have Smart Guides enabled).

Comment: Not related to the design (and probably much too late), but that’s some odd capitalisation in the title there. Why are all the indefinite articles capitalised and then the coordinator isn’t? Why not just normal Title Case (which would not capitalise the articles)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use custom guides https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/ruler-guides.html, or
2. Use proper page margins https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/margins-and-columns.html